# Using MVC Model in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a text box which I am trying to add a "search assist" type effect onto, which displays the top then things in the list of items depending on what the user is typing, the problem is, I have a list of names in my Users model and I am trying to create the search assist in Javascript, is there an easy way to use the models in JavaScript? or perhaps there might be another way that I could look into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it by converting your viewmodel to JSON, then use the js object.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var myJSModel= @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(myViewModel));

</script>
```